# Drawing lines that are cut sequentially in R

Tags: r

I have a script to draw segments in a plot in R.

```
# Make data 
max = 10 
y0 = rep(0,max)
x = 1:max
y = rep(1,max)/1:max
df = data.frame(x,y,y0)

plot(y ~ x, 
     ylim = c(0,max(y)), type = "n")
segments(x0 = df$x, y0 = df$y0, x1 = df$x,y1 = y, lend =2)

# Draw the capping lines 
eps = .1
segments(x0 = df$x-eps, y0 = df$y0, 
         x1 = df$x+eps, y1 = df$y0, lend =2)
segments(x0 = df$x-eps, y0 = df$y, 
         x1 = df$x+eps, y1 = df$y, lend =2)
```

[image]

But I would like to separate the lines with a separator. The result would look like something like this (the red lines were added after, but I'd like them to be black.)
[image]

What you see there is that each line is separated sequentially: the first is not separated, the second in half, third in thirds, etc.

The problem that I realized is that I'd need for loop in for loop in for loop, etc. and this doesn't seem like a good solution.

I was wondering if `expand.grid` could be used for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a loop in a loop solution, and I don't see why not - it works and its not some crazy large computation being done:

```
k <- 10
plot(x = c(0,k), y = c(0,1), typ = "n")

for(i in 1:k){
  points(x = c(i,i), y = c(0,1), typ = "l")
  for(j in 1:(i+1)){
    points(x = c(i-0.1,i+0.1), y = c(seq(0,1,1/i)[j], seq(0,1,1/i) [j]), typ = "l")
  }
}
```

Comment: OK! I see. You used the sequence and the index of the for loop. I was thinking expanding a matrix that would become exponentially larger and indexed by the location of each value. It's much more elegant this solution!.